# Convert CSV to JSON to Pair RDD in Scala Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have CSV data. I first want to convert it into `Json` and then want to convert it into `Pair RDD`.

I was able to do both the things but I am not sure whether it is efficient to do this way and also they the key is not in the expected format.

```
    val df = //some how read the csv data
    val dataset = df.toJSON //This gives the expected json.
    val pairRDD = dataset.rdd.map(record => (JSON.parseFull(record).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("hashKey"), record))
```

Suppose my schema is

```
    root
     |-- hashKey: string (nullable = true)
     |-- sortKey: string (nullable = true)
     |-- score: number (nullable = true)
     |-- payload: string (nullable = true)


    In json
    {
    "hashKey" : "h1",
    "sortKey" : "s1",
    "score" : 1.0,
    "payload" : "data"
    }
    {
    "hashKey" : "h2",
    "sortKey" : "s2",
    "score" : 1.0,
    "payload" : "data"
    }

    EXPECTED result should be
    [1, {"hashKey" : "1", "sortKey" : "2", "score" : 1.0, "payload" : "data"} ]
    [2, {"hashKey" : "h2", "sortKey" : "s2", "score" : 1.0, "payload" : "data"}]


    ACTUAL result I am getting
    [**Some(1)**, {"hashKey" : "1", "sortKey" : "2", "score" : 1.0, "payload" : "data"} ]
    [**Some(2)**, {"hashKey" : "h2", "sortKey" : "s2", "score" : 1.0, "payload" : "data"}]
```

Can can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it's because of `get("hashKey")`. Change it to `getOrElse("hashKey","{defaultKey}")` - when your default key can be `""` or something constant that you declare before.

**Updating to more scala safe way (instead of using `instance of`)**

It's better to change your json parsing to this:

```
dataset.rdd.map(record => JSON.parseFull(record).map{
    case json: Map[String, String] => (json.getOrElse("hashKey",""), record)
    case _ => ("", "")
}.filter{ case (key, record) => key != "" && record != "") }
```

Comment: I will try that. Also, I wanted to know if there is any better way of doing it. This mapping is very slow.